# determine if a looped sequence $A=(a_0\ldots a_n)$ can be represented as $A_i=(p^ia+b\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}{p^k})\pmod M$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Suppose there's a looped sequence $A=(a_0\ldots a_n)$ and, since it is a looped sequence, $a_0=a_n$.

Given $M$, is there a way to determine whether said sequence can be produced by a formula
$$A_i=(p^ia+b\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}{p^k})\pmod M$$

In other words, given a looped sequence $A$, how can we determine if there exist a pair of $(p, b)$ such that the following sequence defines it beautifully?
$$a_0\\(p a_0+b)\pmod M\\(p^2a_0+pb+b)\pmod M\\ \ldots $$

For example, given $M=16$, a looped sequence of $(1, 12,3,6,5,0,7,10,9,4,11,14,13,8,15,2,1)$ can be defined by choosing $p=5$, $b=7$:
$$A_i=(5^ia+7\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}{5^k})\pmod {16}$$

How can we determine if an arbitrary looped sequence can be presented in such manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that a given looped sequence $\{A_n\}$ can be described by a pair of integers $(p,b)$ and the relation
$$
A_n = A_0 p^n + n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} p^k \mod M.
$$
The first thing to note is that we have a recurrence relation:
$$
A_{n+1} = p A_n + b \mod M
$$
and it follows that the same $(p,b)$ combination would be found wherever we start in the loop. The first three elements of the loop are:
$$A_0$$
$$A_1 = p A_0 + b$$
$$A_2 = p A_1 + b$$
and we can combine them to obtain
$$A_2 - 2 A_1 + A_0 = (A_2-A_1) - (A_1-A_0) = (p-1) (A_1 - A_0) $$
$$A_1^2 - A_2 A_0 = A_1(p A_0 +b) - (p A_1 + b) A_0 = b (A_1-A_0)$$
This gives us the two congruence equations:
$$A_2 - 2 A_1 + A_0  \equiv (p-1) (A_1 - A_0) \mod M$$
$$A_1^2 -A_1 A_0  \equiv b (A_1 - A_0) \mod M$$
to be solved for $p-1$ and $b$. These can be solved if and only if 
$$A_2 - 2 A_1 + A_0 \equiv A_1^2 - A_2 A_0 \equiv 0 \mod \gcd(M,A_1-A_0)$$
This double condition is easy to check and when satisfied, the values for $p$ and $b$ follow by solving the congruence equations with the standard algorithm, otherwise no such $(p,b)$ combinations exists that allows the loop to be described via the imposed formula.

Comment: That's a beautiful solution, definitely what I was looking for, thank you! Can you tell me how had you come  up with a solution plan for this problem? Is the problem (or the approach you used) somewhat standard?

Comment: I would not call this a standard problem. Solving such problems depends on intuition, a lot of practice/experience and a bit of luck in trying a successful approach. The ingredients are a sort of standard, but combining them in the proper way is never straightforward.